# Can't install pyenchant on windows even after I installed enchant manually

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyenchant, enchant

I installed pyenchant using `"pip install pyenchant"`
then I installed from the enchant website "ABIWord" and added it to the computer path.
Then when I ran `"import enchent"` from the python console I got:

```
ImportError: The 'enchant' C library was not found. Please install it via your OS package manager, or use a pre-built binary wheel from PyPI.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Is it possible that you're using 64-bit Python or running it on a 64-bit machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can visit http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/download.html and download the Windows installer which will fix this problem and install the library.